# Disable `icomplete` with Emacs `find-file`

Tags: find-file, ivy, icomplete, consult

I have been experimenting with various completion frameworks in Emacs. I am currently using `consult` together with `icomplete`. I like the way things are working for me but I would like to disable `icomplete` for `find-file`. I prefer the traditional Emacs `find-file`.

I have tried this, which did not work:

```
(define-key icomplete-minibuffer-map [remap find-file] nil)
(define-key icomplete-minibuffer-map [remap write-file] nil)
```

I based this on the following which did work when I was experimenting using `ivy`.

```
(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map [remap counsel-find-file] nil)
(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map [remap counsel-describe-variable] nil)
(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map [remap counsel-describe-function] nil)
```

Below are my configurations for icomplete:

```
(require 'icomplete)
(icomplete-mode 1)
(setq icomplete-hide-common-prefix nil)
(setq icomplete-in-buffer t)
(icomplete-vertical-mode)
(bind-key "<tab>" 'icomplete-force-complete minibuffer-local-map)
(bind-key "<return>" 'icomplete-force-complete-and-exit minibuffer-local-map) ; exit with completion
(bind-key "C-j" 'exit-minibuffer minibuffer-local-map) ; force input unconditionally
(bind-key "C-n" 'icomplete-forward-completions minibuffer-local-map)
(bind-key "<down>" 'icomplete-forward-completions minibuffer-local-map)
(bind-key "C-p" 'icomplete-backward-completions minibuffer-local-map)
(bind-key "<up>" 'icomplete-backward-completions minibuffer-local-map)
(bind-key "<C-backspace>" 'icomplete-fido-backward-updir minibuffer-local-map)
```

I would appreciate some help to configure this.

Comment: Advise those commands, so they turn off `icomplete-mode` only for their duration. See the Elisp manual, node [Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) and its subnodes.

Or just define your own commands, which use those commands but which turn-off `icomplete-mode` for the duration, and bind those commands to the keys used for the original commands.

Comment: I have cobbled something together, but now there is no history in the minibuffer when I click the <up> and <down> arrows. 

`;use regular find file key
(defun my-find-file()
  (interactive)
  (icomplete-mode -1)
  (call-interactively 'find-file)
  (icomplete-mode 1))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'my-find-file)`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a little digging for this one.

`find-file` and others like it use the function `find-file-noselect`, which, in turn, uses the function given by the variable `read-file-name-function` in order to read a file name from the minibuffer.

Therefore, you should advise around `read-file-name-function` to disable icomplete (or fido) for all `find-file` type functions.

Beneath the surface, icomplete-mode and fido-mode simply add functions to the `minibuffer-setup-hook`. Looking at these functions, they all check for the variable `icomplete-mode` to be non-nil before running. So to disable icomplete or fido temporarily, you should let-bind the variable `icomplete-mode` to nil.

```lisp
(defun my/disable-icomplete (fun &rest args)
  (let ((icomplete-mode nil))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add read-file-name-function :around #'my/disable-icomplete)
```